# Почему возникают циклические ссылки на папки?

Tags: php, linux, symlinks, nfs

Есть папка `/data`, в ней много ссылок на папки, смонтированные через NFS, напр.

```
/data/2C -> /mnt/nfs/data/2C
```

Трёхуровневая система вложенных папок, PHP получает имя папки, напр. `/data/2C/3D/FF` и создаёт её `if( !file_exists($folderName))`, через `mkdir( $folderName, 0775, true)` – третий параметр означает, что при необходимости надо создавать промежуточные подпапки.

Заметил странный глюк – появляются петли ссылок в случаях, когда совпадают имена первых двух уровней. Например, когда нужна папка `/2C/2C/XX` вместо подпапки `/2C/2C` внутри `/data/2C/` появляется не подпапка, а новая ссылка на `/mnt/nfs/data/2C` – таким образом, образуется циклическая ссылка.

Это баг NFS, ф-ии PHP `mkdir()` или моего кода?

Код примерно такой, ничего особенного:

```
public static function getFolder( $id) {
    $folder = sprintf(
        '%s/%s',
        Config::get( 'mycoolapp.DATA_PATH'),
        self::hexPath( $id)
    );

    // verify / create the folder
    if( !file_exists( $folder)  &&  !mkdir( $folder, 0775, TRUE)) {
        Log::error("Folder creation failed", array( 'folder' => $folder));
    }
```

Метод `hexPath()` просто неким образом из целого id делает шестнадцатиричную строку `XX/YY/ZZZZ`

Всё прекрасно работает на сотнях тысяч папок. Исключение – вот эти единичные глюки при совпадении имён подпапок соседних уровней.

Comment: Скорее всего кода, а можно ключевые моменты показать в вопросе?

Comment: дополнил фрагментом кода, но это вряд ли поможет. Код работает в сотнях тысяч папок, и глюков буквально несколько – везде, совпадают имена папок в соседних уровнях.

Comment: А прибывал просто создать попку из консоли? Может действительно фс считает директорию дубликатом и связывает ссылкой

Comment: `ls -ld` на проблемные каталоги в обеих директориях. Права на */mnt/nfs/data/** какие? Также убедитесь, что вы используете абсолютный путь, например, распечатайте перед созданием содержимое `$folder`.